# Quill Image resize for Angular 2 quill module

Tags: angular

I am trying to use quill-image-resize-module for ngx-quill.I have installed ngx-quill and it is working fine. Now I need to resize the image inside the editor, so I am trying to use it. I found it here [quill-image-resize-module](https://github.com/kensnyder/quill-image-resize-module)

the problem is it is written in JavaScript and I am trying to use it in typescript file(Inside a component), So I got a compiler error.

As they have said that I have to import and register the ImageResize module
But I am getting a compiler error while importing.

Can Anyone help me on using that module.

Thanks

Comment: nice article for image resizing https://blog.almightytricks.com/2020/10/21/ngx-quill-image-resize/

Comment: [While angular build ts compiler uses Quill separate instance for register function that causes the issue of undefining so to avoid that use Global singleton Quill obj. (Using Global window object in angular is not good style as per standard)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48114535/angular-cli-how-to-globally-define-a-variable-window-myvar/69371625#69371625)

Answer (score 11):

As mentioned in the GitHub [issue](https://github.com/kensnyder/quill-image-resize-module/issues/50)
quill-image-resize-module does not work with angular 6 onwards.
Instead, use https://github.com/Fandom-OSS/quill-blot-formatter.
First, install this module via npm

npm install --save quill-blot-formatter

Then in your component -

```js
    import Quill from 'quill';

    // from the index, which exports a lot of useful modules
    import BlotFormatter from 'quill-blot-formatter';

    // or, from each individual module
    import BlotFormatter from 'quill-blot-formatter/dist/BlotFormatter';

    Quill.register('modules/blotFormatter', BlotFormatter);
```

```js
modules = {
    toolbar: {
      container:  [
        ['bold', 'italic', 'underline'],        // toggled buttons
        ['link', 'image', 'video']  ,           // link and image, video
      ],  // Selector for toolbar container
    },
    blotFormatter: {
      // empty object for default behaviour.
    }
    
  }
```

I got this working with angular@7.2.5, angular-cli@7.3.2 and ngx-quill@4.6.11

Comment: This is actually a very good answer. However, It will only resize the first element. Even though it resizes all images, it doesn't really stay like that, unless refreshing the page and doing it again. Did you face any issues with caching?

Comment: Worked on Angular 12 as well. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Hi i figure out how to make this work
First of all make sure that you have this modules installed

```
npm install quill --save
npm install quill-image-resize-module --save
```

an then in `angular.json` add this

```
    "scripts": [
        ...,
        "../node_modules/quill/dist/quill.min.js"
    ]
```

then in your component.ts import Quill in this way

```
import * as QuillNamespace from 'quill';
let Quill: any = QuillNamespace;
import ImageResize from 'quill-image-resize-module';
Quill.register('modules/imageResize', ImageResize);

this.editor_modules = {
      toolbar: {
        container: [
          [{ 'font': [] }],
          [{ 'size': ['small', false, 'large', 'huge'] }],
          ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'strike'],
          [{ 'header': 1 }, { 'header': 2 }],
          [{ 'color': [] }, { 'background': [] }],
          [{ 'list': 'ordered' }, { 'list': 'bullet' }],
          [{ 'align': [] }],
          ['link', 'image']
        ]
      },
      imageResize: true
    };
```

Importing `quill-image-resize-module` in this way will work 100%, by the way I'm using Angular 7.
If you have any question feel free to ask them, I will try to help you.

Comment: Have you done server side rendering in Angular using quill image resize?

Comment: Not yet, but if you'll do it feel free to share with us :)

Comment: This doesn't work for me. The compiler throws the error, that quill-image-resize-module implicitly has an any type and that a declarations file is missing.

Answer (score 2):

First, You cannot use Image-resize with angular-cli. You have to eject web pack from your angular-cli.

> Use `ng eject` to create a webpack.config.js file

Inside the webpack.config.js file, somewhere at the top, paste

```
const webpack = require('webpack')
```

Check for the **plugins** array, at the end, add

```
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
  'window.Quill': 'quill/dist/quill.js'
})
```

Don't forget to add the following to your index.html file

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Aref+Ruqaa|Mirza|Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/KaTeX/0.9.0-alpha1/katex.min.css" integrity="sha384-8QOKbPtTFvh/lMY0qPVbXj9hDh+v8US0pD//FcoYFst2lCIf0BmT58+Heqj0IGyx" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/KaTeX/0.9.0-alpha1/katex.min.js" integrity="sha384-GR8SEkOO1rBN/jnOcQDFcFmwXAevSLx7/Io9Ps1rkxWp983ZIuUGfxivlF/5f5eJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

otherwise, the image-resize widget won't work.

[refer to killerCodeMonkey's example](https://github.com/KillerCodeMonkey/ngx-quill-example)

Sorry I can't provide you with a plunker or sth at the moment.

Comment: still doesnt work getting this error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'parchment' of undefined`

Answer (score 0):

I am using angular/cli 6.0.0, quill-image-resize 3.0.9 and quill-image-resize-module 3.0.0.

The following changes made it work:

> angular.json

```
"architect": {
            "build": {
                "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:browser",
                "options": {
                    "customWebpackConfig": {
                       "path": "./extra-webpack.config.js",
                       "replaceDuplicatePlugins": true
                    },
                    "styles": [
                        "node_modules/quill/dist/quill.core.css", 
                        "node_modules/quill/dist/quill.snow.css"
                    ],
                    "scripts": [
                        "./node_modules/quill/dist/quill.min.js"
                    ]
```

> extra-webpack.config.js

```
var webpack = require("webpack");
var path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  resolve: {
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        'window.Quill': 'quill/dist/quill.js',
        'window.quill': 'quill/dist/quill.js'
    })
  ]
}
```

> Main.ts

```
import Quill from 'quill';
import ImageResize from 'quill-image-resize-module'; 
Quill.register('modules/imageResize', ImageResize);

function _window() : any {
    return window;
}


_window().Quill = Quill;
_window().quill = Quill;
```

And as mentioned by [lordUhuru](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6860188/lorduhuru), I added

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Aref+Ruqaa|Mirza|Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/KaTeX/0.9.0-alpha1/katex.min.css" integrity="sha384-8QOKbPtTFvh/lMY0qPVbXj9hDh+v8US0pD//FcoYFst2lCIf0BmT58+Heqj0IGyx" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/KaTeX/0.9.0-alpha1/katex.min.js" integrity="sha384-GR8SEkOO1rBN/jnOcQDFcFmwXAevSLx7/Io9Ps1rkxWp983ZIuUGfxivlF/5f5eJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

to my index.html

I am not sure if all steps are required. I am still playing around with it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is is the way the module is imported, and it will work in Angular 9 Ivy even, depending on your compiler options in **tsconfig.json**.  Add:

```
"noImplicitAny": false
```

This will also fix the same problem with the ImageDrop module.

Also, check out all the new fixes in the new version with [ngx-quill](https://github.com/KillerCodeMonkey/ngx-quill/issues/91).

Comment: This didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I used jQuery to solve this:

```
const videos = $('iframe.ql-video);
videos.attr("width","853");
videos.attr("height","480");
```

Works fine.