# Angular CLI How to Globally define a variable [window.myVar]

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-cli

I'm trying to use a module that depends on another library, whenever i tried to  register the library in a component i gives me an error in the console :

> Cannot read property 'imports' of undefined

The module name is: quill-image-resize-module
The library is: quill editor.

quill is an html editor.

**MyComponent.ts:**

```
import Quill from 'quill';

// add image resize module
import ImageResize from 'quill-image-resize-module';
Quill.register('modules/imageResize', ImageResize);
```

The error appeared in the console is:

> image-resize.min.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property
>   'imports' of undefined

when i tried to investigate image-resize.min i found this is what causes the error:

```
var d=window.Quill.imports.parchment
```

Now i'm using Angular CLI, i found a working solution but the solution is working with webpack.config.js by declaring this in plugins array:

```
 new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      'window.Quill': 'quill/dist/quill.js'
    })
```

which in turns declare window.Quill Globally.

i'm not sure how to do this in CLI, but i tried to follow some articles by 
declaring :

```
"../node_modules/quill/dist/quill.js"
```

in angular-cli.json file in the scripts array.

but the error is not gone?

Answer (score 0):

myComp.ts

```
import * as Quill from 'quill';
import ImageResize from 'quill-image-resize-module';

 ngAfterViewInit(){

      window['Quill'] = Quill;
      window['Quill'].register({'modules/imageResize': ImageResize});
      this.quillObj = new Quill(this.textEditorDiv, {
        debug: 'error',
        modules: {
          ImageResize: true,
          toolbar: options
        },
        theme: 'snow'
      })};
```

While angular build ts compiler uses Quill separate instance for register function that causes the issue of undefining so to avoid that use Global singleton Quill obj. (Using Global window object in angular is not good style as per standard)